# Angular/Rxjs Conditional nested Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I recently converted a function to dynamically retrieve data from disk rather than memory and during the process went from synchronously returning a variable to returning a Observable.

As part of this conversion every dependent function had to be converted to async via Observables and one of these functions performs a nested conditional call that gets the last scenario for a category or if there was no previous scenario for a category generates gets a default scenario:

```js
public generateScenario(category: string, value: number = 1) : Observable<Scenario>
{
    return this.getHistory(category).map(scenario => {
        if(scenario === null)
        {
            return this.defaultService.getDefault(category, value);
        }
        else
        {
            return scenario;
        }
    });
}
```

Here `this.defaultService.getDefault(category, value)` returns an Observable which means that when the scenario === null branch is executed generateScenario() returns an Observable>.

How do I flatten this out and avoid returning a nested Observable?

Comment: `.do` is for when you *don't* want to return something and change the value of the stream.

Comment: @jonsharpe sorry made a mistake in the sample code, I actually meant to use map

Comment: Checkout this entire article on conditional work in RxJS https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-patterns-conditionally-executing-work/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten this out with various flattening operators in RxJS such as `switch` or `merge`. In this case, `switch` seems most appropriate:

```
this.getHistory(category).switchMap(scenario =>
  scenario === null ? this.defaultService.getCategory(category, value)
  : of(scenario)
);
```

The `of` is required the function passed to `.switchMap` must return an Observable to be flattened/unwrapped/etc.